# How to return value from function to call it sequentially each line with new result

Tags: c#, string, function, random, return-value

Can you help me figure out with two or maybe one problem here, not sure. I'm trying to get string and integer values from several `private static string` which contains different processes each with single different type output, which I want return to call sequentially as function, for further combining.

First I want to say that I don know, how to create such function which can return values to get desired result, if way below is a wrong, and it would be good to see some useful example for this case, but what I'm trying to do here, gives me two problems:

If I want call `b1` then `b2` and again `b1`, I want get unique calculation result from each, but now I got the equal results from each, if I use random number as it is show below, but I suspect in this case the reason of this problem is a wrong use of random inside the `private static string`, also need to figure out, how to use it proper for such case.

Result looks like this:

```
23 23 23
```

But also I think it is not only one, same and main problem here, because if I return some different calculation result, for example choosing from different string set of different  lists separately inside the private static string b1 and b2, result just returns me the same value twice or several times with repeated process in order of sequential calls. I Can't say for sure, but it does not look like the same reason of problem, which can be above. Because it is looks like this:

```
 77 34 77
```

Or to make it clearer, if I choose some word by calculation form string for example: *"hello world, how are you"* and inside each `private static string` I make different calculation to get single word from this string, or from different no mater, I got equal result or correctly to say same result with call of same process twice, just like repeating of result and not as separate call of it:

```
  world you world
```

This sample below show case only with random number, because if last problem is different and has no connection with wrong random number using, reason must be in general approach, and I should go to solve this problem somehow differently.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a1 = b1();
        string a2 = b2();
        string a3 = b1();

        string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);

        Console.WriteLine(comb);
        Console.ReadLine();          
    }

    private static string b1()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int ran1 = random.Next(1, 100);
        return ran1;
    }

    private static string b2()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int ran2 = random.Next(1, 100);
        return ran2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 :**

Example with string return chosen by random number or any other way:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a1 = b1(); 
            string a2 = b2(); 
            string a3 = b1(); 

            string comb  = (a1 + a2 + a3);

            Console.WriteLine(comb);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

 private static string b1()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> mass1 = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
                            { { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" }, { 3, "C" }};

            Random random1 = new Random(); 
            int rndCase2 = random1.Next(1, 4); 
            string key1;
            mass1.TryGetValue(rndCase2, out key1);
            return key1;
        }

private static string b2()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> mass2 = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
                            { { 1, "E" }, { 2, "F" }, { 3, "G" }};

            Random random2 = new Random(); 
            int rndCase2 = random2.Next(1, 4); 
            string key2;
            mass2.TryGetValue(rndCase2, out key2);
            return key2;
        }
```

Result is:

```
AEA
```

**EDIT 2: (SOLVED)**

```
 class Program
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a1 = b1();
            string a2 = b2();
            string a3 = b1();

            string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);

            Console.WriteLine(comb);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string b1()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> mass1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                        { { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" }, { 3, "C" }};

            return mass1[random.Next(1, 4)];
        }

        private static string b2()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> mass2 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                        { { 1, "E" }, { 2, "F" }, { 3, "G" }};

            return mass2[random.Next(1, 4)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the line `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a1);` contains a typo and must be `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);` (note the final `a3`)

Comment: @DefColin: Sorry, I don't follow the last phrase " but newer AFB for example, seems like repeated call just returns not just equal as it was with random number but the same result.", could you, please, put in other words. Do you have, say, too *many* / too *few* `A` than expected? Do suspect that the sequence is *skewed* one?

Comment: @DefColin: It seems that you want `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);` (please, notice `a3`), not `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a1);` (please, notice the *second* `a1`)

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko ohh yes and I was convinced that there is no typo, but it was there so, my bad, now everything is alright. Both answers below works. thank you.

Comment: @Hans Kesting  yes true it was there, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Random` generator when created as `new Random()` initializes from the *system timer*, there's a good chance that you have three *identical* generators (with *identical* sequences) in all three calls. Move `Random` out the methods:

```
   class Program {
     // simplest, not thread safe
     private static Random random = new Random();

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Random random = new Random();
        string a1 = b1();
        string a2 = b2();
        string a3 = b1();

        string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3); // <- please, notice "a3" instead of second "a1"

        Console.WriteLine(comb);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }

     private static string b1()
     {
        return random.Next(1, 100).ToString();
     }

     private static string b2()
     {
        return random.Next(1, 100).ToString();
     }
   }
```

In your edited code, please, follow the same principle: *do not create* `Random` instances, but use `static` one:

```
    private static string b1()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> mass1 = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
                        { { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" }, { 3, "C" }};

        return mass1[random.Next(1, 4)];
    }

    private static string b2()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> mass2 = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
                        { { 1, "E" }, { 2, "F" }, { 3, "G" }};

        return mass2[random.Next(1, 4)];
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I edit my question once again with this code inside, but as you can see, it still does not give me the desired result, as I described it in the second part of my question, maybe I'm just wrong in the decision, waiting for a individual execution with several repeats of same call in the order with `private static string`

Comment: @DefColin: it seems that you've made a typo: it should be `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);` (please, notice `a3`) instead of current `string comb = (a1 + a2 + a1);`

Answer (score 1):

use one `Random` instance only

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        string a1 = b1(random);
        string a2 = b2(random);
        string a3 = b1(random);

        string comb = (a1 + a2 + a3);

        Console.WriteLine(comb);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static string b1(Random random)
    {
        int ran1 = random.Next(1, 100);
        return ran1.ToString();
    }

    private static string b2(Random random)
    {
        int ran2 = random.Next(1, 100);
        return ran2.ToString();
    }
}
```

**edit 1**

the same applies for those other `b1()` and `b2()` methods of yours:

```
    private static string b1(Random random)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> mass1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                    { { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" }, { 3, "C" }};

        return mass1[random.Next(1, 4)];
    }

    private static string b2(Random random)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> mass2 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                    { { 1, "E" }, { 2, "F" }, { 3, "G" }};

        return mass2[random.Next(1, 4)];
    }
```

while `Main()` stays the same as in my previous edit

Comment: Hello, I edit my question with string example. Yes you answer to the first part of the question, thank you. But can you help me to get how to do it with last example with string chosen by random number or some other way

Comment: see edited answer. My test return `comb` strings with first and last characters different as well as equal

Comment: For my case is more suitable to use `private static Random random = new Random(); ` as it show in example below. So I'm going to mark it as answer. but both answers are working for me, and in general the same. thank you